# Aggregating over 2 columns of a dataframe R

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

My dataframe is as follows

```
TreeID    Species    PlotNo    Basalarea
12345       A          1         120
13242       B          7         310
14567       D          8         250
13245       B          1         305
13426       B          1         307
13289       A          3         118
```

I used

```
newdata<- aggregate(Basalarea~PlotNo+Species, data, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

to aggregate all the values such that

```
 newdata
     Species    PlotNo    Basalarea
       A          1         120
       A          3         118
       B          1         some value
       B          7         310
       D          8         250
```

This is great but I would like a dataframe such that

```
PlotNo    A       B            D
 1        120    some value    0
 3        118    0             0
 7        0      310           0
 8        0      0            250
```

How do I obtain the above dataframe?

Comment: Please show data for a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your attempts at a solution. SO members are volunteers to help troubleshoot programming issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have provided an example of what I am trying to obtain. Hope someone helps me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast` to convert from long to wide format.  Specify the `fun.aggregate` as `sum`.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, PlotNo~Species, value.var='Basalarea', sum)
#  PlotNo   A   B   D
#1      1 120 612   0
#2      3 118   0   0
#3      7   0 310   0
#4      8   0   0 250
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be using `xtabs`.  By default it gets the `sum` of the 'Basalarea' for the combinations of 'PlotNo' and 'Species'.

```
xtabs(Basalarea~PlotNo+Species, df1)
#     Species
#PlotNo   A   B   D
#     1 120 612   0
#     3 118   0   0
#     7   0 310   0
#     8   0   0 250
```

Or another `base R` option is `tapply`

```
with(df1, tapply(Basalarea, list(PlotNo, Species), FUN=sum))
```

Comment: Excellent alternatives, but doesn't xtabs return a non-dataframe object? And tapply does not show PlotNo.

Comment: @Parfait If it is needed, `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(..` can be used to convert to `data.frame`.  Regarding the 'PlotNo', it is just the row.names of the output.  So, if the OP needed it, it can be made in to a new column.